# When a user login fails, is it possible to say "Password incorrect" or "Username does not exist" instead of the default message?

Tags: 7, users, forms

When a user types an incorrect user name or password, by default Drupal gives this message: "Sorry, unrecognized username or password."

To help my sometimes clueless users (and my clueless self), I'd like to provide more helpful messages to specify exactly what is wrong.

In other words:

- Incorrect password= "The password you provided is incorrect."
- Account does not exist= "No account is registered for USERNAME."

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: The message is like that for security reasons...Changing it to how you're suggesting would make it easy for an attacker to find out which usernames are valid in the system and concentrate brute force attacks against them. Keeping the message ambiguous is good security practice.

Comment: I strongly suggest you go by @Clive 's comment and keep the message as ambiguous it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message is set in `user.module` in the [user_login_final_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) function.  It's set as a bog-standard `form_set_error()` so can't really be over-ridden.  Looking at it, it also doesn't differentiate between whether or not the username or password is incorrect, so you wouldn't really be able to do anything useful.

As Clive mentioned, it's much better practice to keep a degree of ambiguity in certain error messages, and seeing as how this isn't wrapped in any kind of theme function and doesn't have separate behaviours for whether the username exists or password was incorrect, you're probably better off leaving it as is.

One last option you have is to user a `hook_form_alter()` on `user_form` to set an extra validation callback, and then check for the user name yourself.

Example:

(I can't remember the $form_state for the user form, so you'll have to `die()` or `dpm()` that yourself)

```
function mymodule_check_username_exists($form, &$form_state){
  $user_exists = user_load_by_name($form_state['name']);

  if ($user_exists == FALSE ) {
   form_set_error('name', t('This username does not exist'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check [`user_login_authenticate_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_authenticate_validate/7) and [`user_login_final_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7)

I think you can work your way using anyone of those.

Hope that helps.

Muhammad